# Should we build typescript into js when uploading to server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

We are always using nodejs and we write code using vanilla JavaScript (.js extension). It's working fine, but currently we decided to create nodejs app using typescript. Unfortunately, we encounter many errors in building it (ts -> js). It is require .js code to run in the server? or just upload typescript files then run it in server using ts-node?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: What sort of 'errors' are you encountering? If they're to do with the actual code you might want to consider resolving the errors first

Comment: Like its running in typescript but when we build it in using tsc and run it in dist. Some packages wont work. It is okay to just upload backend typescript not compiling it to javascript?

Comment: If you have issues with the packages you are using, as the answer below suggests you need to resolve those. NodeJS _only_ reads JavaScript, so you need to compile at some point and so you will likely hit the same errors you have either way

Comment: Okay thanks tom , so it is a bad practice to run typescript in production? by using ts-node?

Comment: It's not bad practice. `ts-node` compiles the typescript to javascript at runtime, so it's actually still just running JavaScript code in the end

Answer (score 4):

> Unfortunately, we encounter many errors in building it (ts -> js).

If they're errors in the code (TypeScript-related or otherwise), you need to resolve those before trying to use it in production.

> It is require .js code to run in the server?

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) is a **JavaScript** runtime, it doesn't understand TypeScript.

You can:

- Compile your TypeScript to JavaScript before deploying; or
- Use [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) or similar to compile it just-in-time; or
- Use a different runtime, like [Deno](https://deno.land/) which handles TypeScript directly (basically by compiling just-in-time).

Note that when using one of the just-in-time options, it's really important to ensure that the code compiles cleanly by compiling it during development and staging. Your production environment shouldn't be the first place a TypeScript compilation error shows up.

Comment: It is okay to use typescript in production? by using ts-node?

Comment: @thegreytangent - That's entirely up to you and your team.

Comment: Nevertheless, type checking should be done before deployment (in the CI). `ts-node` can be used with the `--transpile-only` option in order to reduce memory footprint. See https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/104